# Exibir o conteúdo de um botão e fazer ele sumir depois de um período

Tags: android, button

Sou totalmente novato com android studio e estou tentando criar um joguinho da memória, o jogo consiste em uma série de botões, uma fila 4x4, todos os botões aparecem sendo uma **"?"** quando você clica no botão ele exibe o número guardado dentro dele, eu queria fazer o conteúdo apresentado dentro do botão sumir depois de alguns segundos, já que se trata de um jogo da memória, conseguem me ajudar sobre qual função utilizar para conseguir fazer isso?

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btn1.setText("1");

                }
            });
```

O comando btn1.setText("1"); esta pegando o conteúdo do botão, ele fica pra sempre e não some, ou seja ele não volta a ser uma ?

2 Dúvida, Tenho um botão INICIAR, quando clicasse nele queria que meu text view que se trata de um Contador, começasse a contar o tempo que a pessoa levaria para fechar o joguinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btn1.setText("1");
        // O Texto do botão voltará a ser "?" em 5 segundos
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn1.setText("?");
            }
        }, 5000); // 5 segundos
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou perfeitamente, o conteúdo aparece e some depois de 5 segundos, e se o usuário acertar os dois botões com o mesmo conteúdo, como faço pra eles não sumirem mais, apenas em caso de acerto.

Comment: Você pode colocar todos um botões em uma array (```Button[]```). Quando qualquer um deles for clicado, faça um loop e verifique se cada botão tem o mesmo texto do botão que foi clicado (```getText()```), se sim, interrompa o loop e não o handler postar o método